# Getting editor placeholder in source file

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an app, that make an api call, and display some data from the server resposne. For now, I'm unable to lauch the app, because I'm getting `editor placeholder in source file` error, in my main struct, and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Here's some code

SecondLabsApp

```
 @main
    struct SecondLabsApp: App {
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ListView(countries: <#T##[Country]#>)
            }
        }
    }
```

ListView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemView: View {
    let country: Country
    
    var body: some View{
        Text(country.flag)
            .font(.largeTitle)
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:0){
            Text(country.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text(country.region)
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View{
@State var countries: [Country]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List{
                ForEach(countries){country in
                    NavigationLink{
                        HStack{
                            Text(country.flag)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                            Text(country.name)
                                .foregroundColor(.mint)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                        }.padding(10)
                        Text("Region: \(country.region)")
                        Text("Population: \(country.population)")
                        Text("Area: \(country.area) km") + Text("2").font(Font.footnote).baselineOffset(6.0)
                        Text("Currency: \(country.currency)")
                    } label: {
                        ItemView(country: country)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Countries")
                .onAppear{
                    CountryAPI().getCountries { countries in
                        self.countries = countries
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CountriesAPI

```
import Foundation


struct Country: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let region: String
    let flag: String
//    let capital: String
    let population: Int
    let area: Int
    let currency: String
    
    let capital: [String]
    let flags: Flags
    
}
struct Flags: Codable {
    let png: URL
    let svg: URL
}

struct CountryAPI {
    func getCountries(completion: @escaping ([Country]) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let session = URLSession.shared


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, urlResponse, error in
            if let data = data {
                // let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                // print(string)
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let countries = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: data)
                    print(countries)
                    completion(countries)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    completion([])
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

How I can deal with such error? I'm kinda new to the xcode, so I feel a bit lost with it.

Comment: `<#T##[Country]#>` it's the Placeholder (converted as text), you don't see the `<#T##` and `#>` in Xcode, just `Country` in "bubble". Replace it with "real code". As I guess, it should be an empty list at first, `ListView(countries: [])` should work (initialized with an empty array)

Comment: @Larme that was it, thank you.